# Reverse proxy using nginx to add CSP header in docker application

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to test custom CSP header in dotCMS application. For this, I am using nginx reverse proxy. My nginx server is unable to connect with dotCMS. It is giving me connection refused error.

Here is my code for nginx:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://dotcms:8082; # This should match your dotcms service name and port
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file config for dotCMS:

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  db_net:
  opensearch-net:
  http_net:

volumes:
  cms-shared:
  dbdata:
  opensearch-data:

services:
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.3.6
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elastic-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - data
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1G"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1 # Set memlock to unlimited (no soft or hard limit)
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # Maximum number of open files for the opensearch user - set to at least 65536
        hard: 65536
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

  dotcms:
    image: dotcms/dotcms:latest
    environment:
      CMS_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xmx1g'
      LANG: 'C.UTF-8'
      TZ: 'UTC'
      DB_BASE_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://db/dotcms"
      DB_USERNAME: 'dotcmsdbuser'
      DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
      DOT_ES_AUTH_BASIC_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      DOT_ES_ENDPOINTS: 'https://opensearch:9200'
      DOT_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      DOT_DOTCMS_CLUSTER_ID: 'dotcms-production'
      CUSTOM_STARTER_URL: 'https://repo.dotcms.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/dotcms/starter/20220713/starter-20220713.zip'
    depends_on:
      - opensearch
      - db
    volumes:
      - cms-shared:/data/shared
      # - {license_local_path}/license.zip:/data/shared/assets/license.zip
    networks:
      - db_net
      - opensearch-net
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
      - "8443:8443"

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=400' -c 'shared_buffers=128MB'
    environment:
      "POSTGRES_USER": 'dotcmsdbuser'
      "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": 'password'
      "POSTGRES_DB": 'dotcms'
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - db_net

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      - http_net
    depends_on:
      - dotcms
```

The code should connect to the nginx server and the CSP header should be added but I am just having access to dotcms in its own port (8080) but not in the port specified by nginx(port 80).